# Updating a list view with data binding after adding item to list

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to update a data-binded list view.

This is the desired behaviour:

The user writes the title of the item he/she likes to add to the list and submits his input with the enter key.

The list should update, but it doesn't.

```
private void NewSubject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        TextBox newSubject = sender as TextBox;

        Subjects.Add(new Subject { Title = newSubject.Text });

        SubjectsList.ItemsSource = Subjects;

        newSubject.Text = "";
    }
}
```

this is the xaml code excerpt:

```
    <DockPanel Margin="4">
        <TextBox x:Name="NewSubject" KeyDown="NewSubject_KeyDown" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0 8 0 0" Padding="4" />
        <ListView Name="SubjectsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
```

Where could be my mistake?

Comment: It would work out of the box (without re-assigning ItemsSource) if Subjects would be an ObservableCollection. We don't know.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens !!! :D it works!